# Is it possible for MySQL to calculate average time from a time series?

Tags: mysql, analytics

Say you have a generics analytics tool that would keep track of page views and you want to get the total time between the first and last event of each user.  Is it possible with a window function?

Here is the example data:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `user_events` VALUES 
  (1,'user1','home','2019-03-03 10:00:00'),
  (2,'user2','home','2019-03-03 10:00:11'),
  (3,'user1','about','2019-03-03 10:00:23'),
  (4,'user1','contact','2019-03-03 10:00:47'),
  (5,'user2','services','2019-03-03 10:01:04'),
  (6,'user2','contact','2019-03-03 10:01:15'),
  (7,'user1','home','2019-03-03 18:20:34'),
  (8,'user1','services','2019-03-03 18:20:37');
```

Which gives us this to start with:

```
mysql> select * from user_events;
+----+-------+----------+---------------------+
| id | user  | page     | ts                  |
+----+-------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | user1 | home     | 2019-03-03 10:00:00 |
|  2 | user2 | home     | 2019-03-03 10:00:11 |
|  3 | user1 | about    | 2019-03-03 10:00:23 |
|  4 | user1 | contact  | 2019-03-03 10:00:47 |
|  5 | user2 | services | 2019-03-03 10:01:04 |
|  6 | user2 | contact  | 2019-03-03 10:01:15 |
|  7 | user1 | home     | 2019-03-03 18:20:34 |
|  8 | user1 | services | 2019-03-03 18:20:37 |
+----+-------+----------+---------------------+
```

Our expected results after this is all done is the following:

- user1 = 47 seconds
- user2 = 64 seconds
- user1 session2 = 3 seconds

Which would give us an average of 38 seconds

There is this blog which appears to use Postgres as an example https://blog.jooq.org/2015/05/12/use-this-neat-window-function-trick-to-calculate-time-differences-in-a-time-series/  The last part of the blog mentions using a 'reset' to start the timer over, however I'm getting stuck converting the Postgres to MySQL

I followed the alternative to FILTER from https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->   COUNT(CASE WHEN page = 'home' THEN 1 END)  OVER (ORDER BY ts) c,
    ->   ts
    -> FROM user_events;
+---+---------------------+
| c | ts                  |
+---+---------------------+
| 1 | 2019-03-03 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 2019-03-03 10:00:11 |
| 2 | 2019-03-03 10:00:23 |
| 2 | 2019-03-03 10:00:47 |
| 2 | 2019-03-03 10:01:04 |
| 2 | 2019-03-03 10:01:15 |
| 3 | 2019-03-03 18:20:34 |
| 3 | 2019-03-03 18:20:37 |
+---+---------------------+
```

But I obviously need some kind of grouping so the 2nd users home page visit doesn't reset the first.

I've also tried just a simple min/max

```
mysql> select TIMEDIFF(max(ts),min(ts)) as session_length, user
    -> from user_events
    -> group by user;
+----------------+-------+
| session_length | user  |
+----------------+-------+
| 08:20:37       | user1 |
| 00:01:04       | user2 |
+----------------+-------+
```

But again I need a reset so user1's 2 sessions don't get grouped.

Is what I am attempting to do with the given data even possible or do I need another "session_id" (or some such) column to help with the querying

Comment: What are you defining as the "first and last event" of each user?  This is not clear from your question, and I can imagine multiple ways of defining this.

Comment: ...in other words, define 'session'

Comment: For the sake of this example, a session starts when you visit the 'home' page.  The previous event to the 'home' page would then become the last event. I realize in the real world a user can start on any page, however for our app we always have a "Start" event no matter where they start in the app, which I am equating to the 'home' page.  @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately as you have correctly guessed, you would need a session_id field in your data model in order to accurately identify that each user is actually unique. The only way around this would be to set a default timer value that when exceeded would deem the user to have created a new session but this is very cumbersome and I would not recommend this by any means as it presents other issues and the calculation becomes exponentially harder to process.

User 1 appears twice in your example making it very difficult to obtain the results you are after from the data model as it stands. Anyone looking at this without your results would say user1 spent 8 hours 20 minutes and 30 seconds on the system.

What you are after can be achieved if a session_id was inserted into the user_events table.
You could then find the time spent by each user session (in seconds) by performing a query like that below

```
    SELECT session_id, max(ts) as end_of_session, min(ts) as start_of_session, 
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(max(ts)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(min(ts))) as delta_ts
    FROM user_events
    GROUP BY session_id
    ORDER BY session_id
```

Then you can wrap this around a call which works out the average duration across all unique user sessions by a query like that below

```
SELECT avg(delta_ts)
FROM
(    
    SELECT session_id, max(ts) as end_of_session, min(ts) as start_of_session, 
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(max(ts)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(min(ts))) as delta_ts
    FROM user_events
    GROUP BY session_id
    ORDER BY session_id
)q_inner
```

This example works as you would expect if the session_id field is added to your model.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `user_events` VALUES 
  (1,'z1a64','user1','home','2019-03-03 10:00:00'),
  (2,'wopa1','user2','home','2019-03-03 10:00:11'),
  (3,'z1a64','user1','about','2019-03-03 10:00:23'),
  (4,'z1a64','user1','contact','2019-03-03 10:00:47'),
  (5,'wopa1','user2','services','2019-03-03 10:01:04'),
  (6,'wopa1','user2','contact','2019-03-03 10:01:15'),
  (7,'n3dhe','user1','home','2019-03-03 18:20:34'),
  (8,'n3dhe','user1','services','2019-03-03 18:20:37');


SELECT avg(delta_ts)
FROM
(    
    SELECT session_id, max(ts) as end_of_session, min(ts) as start_of_session, 
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(max(ts)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(min(ts))) as delta_ts
    FROM user_events
    GROUP BY session_id
    ORDER BY session_id
)q_inner
```